# hudson : map SVN credentials to emails

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, build-process, jenkins

I bet this is highlighted in documentation somewhere but I'm a bit lazy right now.

How do we set up mapping from SVN credentials to emails we use in notifications in case Hudson observes a failed build after a checkin?
It would be nice to compare TeamCity extensive notifications setup with the same of Hudson or Jenkins.

Just some link to the proper place in the docs would do as well.

Thanks,
Anton

**UPD**: the main problem we face now is to notify only the offender, not all developers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How constrain the list of users who can receive the e-mail in jenkins on build failure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777618/how-constrain-the-list-of-users-who-can-receive-the-e-mail-in-jenkins-on-build-f)

Answer (score 5):

Under *Post-build actions* for your job, you can enable email notifications and check *Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build*.

Jenkins will accumulate user information from the SVN commits. There is possibly more dynamic ways to do this, but under *People* you will see user names Jenkins recognizes. You can configure the email address corresponding to each user.

This is valid for [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) 1.413 - don't know if this functionality is available in your Hudson version.